# Javers InstantiationError in spring environment

Tags: javers

When trying to instantiate Javers using:

```
JaversBuilder.javers().build()
```

I keep getting the following runtime exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.picocontainer.monitors.AbstractComponentMonitor
```

I am using javers-core 2.9.1 in a spring environment, however, I do not want to use any of the repository functionality, I just want to be use the object diff. In the getting started documentation it says you can simply use: Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build(); and then compare to objects.

In a spring environment is there more that needs to be done? I am using JPA Entities and MappedSuperclasses (my object extends multiple levels of MappedSuperClasses of which the final one has a JPA @ID annotation.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Not enough data, reproduction scenario is required (a failing test case). This thread will be continued here https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/493

Comment: I had another dependency that an older version of pico container as a dependency.  Excluding that version fixed my issue.